# Rails rake db:schema:dump error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I run `rake db:schema:dump`

I get the following error:

> rake aborted!
>   (): could not find expected ':' while scanning a simple key at line 18
>   column 3
>
> Tasks: TOP => db:schema:dump => db:load_config
>
> (See full trace by running task with --trace)

How can I fix this?

Comment: could u run your command with --trace and post the output

Comment: Could you please post your database.yml file?

Answer (score 11):

I found that the ":" separators must be followed by a space before the value. For instance, this makes the rake `db:create` command crash:

In the database.yml file:

```
development:
adapter: mysql2
encoding: utf8
reconnect: true
database: Some_Silly_Database_development
pool: 5
username: Jobs
password:anythingapple
socket: /tmp/mysql.sock
```

By simply inserting a space between the colon separating *password* and *anythingapple*, like this: `password: anythingapple`
the Rake db:create ran fine.  One neglected space makes the diff. Hope this helps

Comment: Oh man, thanks so much for that one.  I was chasing that problem for a few hours, and it was just a SPACE I was missing!  Haha, such is the nature of this game.  :-)

Comment: thanks a lot! the key and the value must be separated by a " "(space)

Comment: wow thanks! you saved me some hours of work. In my case the ' ' error was in other .yml file in the config dir, the result was the same

Answer (score 3):

Check you database.yml file.  It sounds like  you have a line missing the :